# OpenDJ Control-panel doesn't synchronize newly created attribute and object types

Tags: ldap, opendj

I have been working with open dj for some time now, I newly created attribute and object types through the control panel. Unfortunately OpenDJ doesn't seems to load those attribute and object types from the server.

I tried using Apache Directory studio to check if those attribute are available, it turns out Apache Directory Studio could load them in it schema editor. I also checked the file and directory under the schema, the types seems to be defined.

Please how can I get those attributes to be loaded as I want to used them to create a new object class with those attributes included.

In the meantime I have decided to edit the 99-user.ldif file after creating the object class, then I will add the attribute manually, then restart the server.

The process is getting too combersom, it needs to be streamlined.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue that has been fixed years ago, while I was working at ForgeRock.
The controlPanel has been discontinued since then.
I wonder which version of OpenDJ you are seeing these symptoms with?

Comment: I am using the latest version of OpendDj, if the control panel has been discontinued, are there recommended alternatives?